# R: how to calculate if any of column in each row satisfies a condition without loop

Tags: r, data-manipulation

```
dat  = runif(10,1,10)
dat2 = runif(10,1,10)
dat3 = runif(10,1,10)
data = rbind(dat,dat2,dat3)
```

In the case of above data, I am wondering how I can filter out rows as long as there is one element in that row exceeding 5.

I know that I can use loop to achieve this, but I am wondering if there is more succinct way to do this.

Comment: Maybe `subset(data, !(rowSums(data >= 5) >= 1))` ?

Comment: How about `data[!apply(data > 5,1,any),]`?

Comment: Or `data[rowSums(data >= 5) == 0L,]` to avoid the negation.

Comment: Who is downvoting legitimate answers?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
data[apply(data>5, 1, sum)>0,]
```

This says "for condition *having more than zero number exceeding 5 in each row*, filter data".

Answer (score -1):

```
data[do.call(pmax,data.frame(data))<=5,]
```

Cheers,
Bert